# Why can I dynamic_cast to a non-virtual class?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Why does this compile, if `A` has no virtual functions?

```cpp
class A {
    int a = 42;
};

class B {

    void* f() {
        return dynamic_cast<A*>(this);
    }

    virtual void my_virtual() {};
};
```

Note: Though it makes no sense to write something like this, this was the result of a refactor, after the base class was removed. I feel like there should have been a compiler error.

Comment: [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is largely a run-time explicit conversion. It should return a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not a requirement, and it shouldn't be an error.

Consider the following addition to your classes (after making `B::f()` public):

```
class C: public A, public B
{
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    void* p = c.f();
}
```

which should, and does, return to `p` a pointer to the `A` subobject of `c`.

Only the conversion source is required to be of polymorphic type, and that is only if it is not known at compile time that the target is a base class of the source.
In the latter case, a decent compiler will not do any conversion at runtime.